# Why does i2c not work on my raspberry pi 3 model B?

Tags: linux, i2c, driver, software-development

I have the raspberry pi 3 model B and would like to communicate over i2c. I have heard that the bcm2835 and bcm2837 chip ar almost identical, so I should be able to use the bcm2835 library to communicate over i2c, yet I don't see anything happening.

- I have 2 pull ups from 10k
- this code shows me that I always get a NACK
- a logic analyzer that shows me that the serial lines are always high and never go low
- yes I did enable i2c in raspberry pi configurations > interfaces > i2c

Could anybody explain me what I am doing wrong?

*EDIT:*

```
- i2cdetect -y 1

    pi@raspberrypi:~ $ i2cdetect -y 1

         0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f

    00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

    10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

    20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

    30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

    40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

    50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

    60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 68 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

    70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --                         

    pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

- This is the code I use to communicate, reason is always equal to 1 (=NACK):

  ```
  #include <bcm2835.h>

  #include <stdio.h>


  #define slaveAddress 0x68

  int main(int argc, char **argv) {

      char commands[1];
      uint8_t reason;

      bcm2835_init();
      bcm2835_i2c_begin();

      printf("i2c busy\n");
      bcm2835_i2c_setSlaveAddress(slaveAddress);
      bcm2835_i2c_set_baudrate(1000);
      bcm2835_delay(500);

      commands[0] = 0x35;
      reason = bcm2835_i2c_write(commands, 1);

      printf("reason: %d\n", reason);
      return 0;
  }
  ```

In the BCM2835 header file, I modified the base address from 0x20000000 to 0x3F00000000 (neither of them worked).

- this is my setup

[image]

- I tried to communicate with the module using the wiringPi library. That worked. So the issue has to do with my code somehow....

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56989/discussion-on-question-by-qjbihftc-why-does-i2c-not-work-on-my-raspberry-pi-3-mo).

Comment: it looks like you may have sda and scl reversed

Comment: @SteveRobillard sorry this is an "older" picture. In the meantime I already put them correctly. But the issue lays elsewhere.

Comment: Please add a picture of the connections you are **actually using**, explain how you have enabled I2C, cut n' paste the output from `i2cdetect -y 1`, and include an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (not a link).

Comment: @goldilocks updated my answer

Comment: It is progress to see the device on the bus.  If it's an ITG 3205 gyroscope try reading with http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_i2c_ITG3205_py

Comment: @goldilocks I think my question is clear now, can you "unblock" it?

Comment: Your question was reopened an hour ago.

Comment: @joan as an update I tested the sensor with the wiringPi library and it seems to work. The issue is related to the code I posted above somehow....

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/bcm2835 is probably the best place for support for the bcm2835 library.

Comment: Sounds uninitialized, check the return of bcm2835_i2c_begin is 1? Using sudo?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code is missing pin initialization

Do so by using `void bcm2835_gpio_fsel(uint8_t pin, uint8_t mode)`

Also consider your access level

> If the library runs with any other effective UID (ie not root), then
>     bcm2835_init() will attempt to open /dev/gpiomem, and, if
>     successful, will only permit GPIO operations. In particular,
>     bcm2835_spi_begin() and bcm2835_i2c_begin() will return false and all
>     other non-gpio operations may fail silently or crash.

Check for bcm_init's return value if you are unsure. Nonzero means you are good to go (=root).

Modifying the base address to 0x3F00000000 should not be necessary as of the RPi3 (although it is correct that they do differ):

> On RPI 2, the peripheral addresses are different and the bcm2835 library gets them 
>     from reading /proc/device-tree/soc/ranges. This is only availble with recent versions of the kernel on RPI 2.

(2 and 3 have the same base address)

This mechanism depends on the presence of `/proc/device-tree/soc/ranges` in your filesystem. So go check that and look up how to enable **device-tree support** in case it is not visible.

If you are done checking all of these and it is still not working, the next step is to consider `void bcm2835_i2c_setClockDivider(uint16_t divider)`